# How do i make my Flask App run on an HTTPS link instead of a HTTP one?

Tags: flask, https, web-applications, web-development-server, pyngrok

I'm running a website on Flask on an http link (the one provided by flask during development) but i would like to turn it https. How do i do it?

Searching on the web i've only found answers related to old Flask versions (i'm currently using Flask_2.2.4) where you could simply insert a parameter inside the "app.run()" function indicating that the server should be https, but i think that it's not working anymore.
Anything would be helpful, thank you in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using  flask run you can add --cert=adhoc to the end.
Example: `flask run --cert=adhoc`.
If you're using app.run you can do `app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')`.
However you will get a warning from your browser saying this site is not secure, etc.
In order to do this you need to do `pip install pyopenssl`